# SwiftUI - how to include a second filter to retrieve CoreData

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I am developing an iOS app using SwiftUI. In the **ContentView** after it loads it displays the **SelectAccountView** for the user to select an account. When the process returns back to **ContentView**, I want to use the *selectedAccount* value to filter the CoreData.

Below is the ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State private var finalAmount: Float = 0
    @State private var selectedEntry: CFTEntry? // Move selectedEntry to ContentView
    @State private var isPresentingEntryEditView = false
    @State private var isPresentingSettingsView = false
    @State private var isPresentingDeleteView = false
    @State private var isPresentingAccountsView = true
    @State private var selectedAccount: CFTAccounts? // Added selectedAccount
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: CFTEntry.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CFTEntry.cftDate, ascending: false)])
    var entries: FetchedResults<CFTEntry>
    
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            VStack 
            {
                HStack
                {
                    Image("Wallet") // Add your desired icon system name
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Cash Flow Tracker")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
//                        .padding(.top, 1)
                    Spacer()
                }
                HStack
                {
                    if let account = selectedAccount 
                    { // Show selected account name
                        Text("Account: \(account.cftAccount ?? "")")
                            .font(.headline)
//                            .fontWeight(.bold)
//                            .padding(.top, 1)
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        Text("Please, select an Account") // Display message if no account is selected
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
//                            .padding(.top, 1)
                    }
                }
                HStack(spacing: 50)
                {
                    // Descriptions
                    Button(action: {
                        // Show EntrySettingsView
                        isPresentingSettingsView = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")  //.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    }
                    // Add New Entry
                    Button(action: {
                        isPresentingEntryEditView = true
                        selectedEntry = nil
                    })
                    {
                        VStack
                        {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle") //.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
//                            Text("Add Entry")
//                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                        }
                    }
                    // Delete Entries
                    Button(action: {
                        isPresentingDeleteView = true
                    })
                    {
                        VStack
                        {
                            Image(systemName: "trash.circle") //.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
                    }
                    // Accounts
                    Button(action: {
                        isPresentingAccountsView = true
                    })
                    {
                        VStack
                        {
                            Image(systemName: "building.columns.circle") //.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
                    }
                }

                EntryListView(entries: entries, selectedEntry: $selectedEntry, bindTotalAmount: $finalAmount, updateTotalAmount: calculateTotalAmount)
                { totalAmount in
                    // Update the totalAmount in the ContentView
                    finalAmount = totalAmount
                }
                .onAppear 
                {
                    // Calculate totalAmount when the view appears initially
                    finalAmount = calculateTotalAmount()
                }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave)) { _ in
                    // Calculate totalAmount when the managed object context is saved (i.e., an entry is added or edited)
                    finalAmount = calculateTotalAmount()
                }
                .onTapGesture
                {
                    isPresentingEntryEditView = true
                }
                    //.padding(.top, 20)
                
                //Display the grand total at the bottom of the screen
                HStack
                {
                    //"$\(entry.cftAmount, specifier: "%.2f")"
                    Text("Projected Total $\(finalAmount, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                        .padding(.trailing, 10)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingEntryEditView) 
            {
                EntryEditView(selectedEntry: $selectedEntry, bindTotalAmount: $finalAmount, selectedAccount: $selectedAccount)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSettingsView) 
            {
                EntrySettingsView()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingDeleteView)
            {
                DeleteEntriesView()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingAccountsView)
            {
                // Pass selectedAccount as binding
                SelectAccountView(selectedAccount: $selectedAccount)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func calculateTotalAmount() -> Float
    {
        var calculatedTotalAmount: Float = 0.0
        
        let filteredEntries: [CFTEntry]
        if let selectedAccount = selectedAccount
        {
            filteredEntries = entries.filter { $0.cftAccount == selectedAccount.cftAccount }
        } 
        else
        {
            filteredEntries = entries.map { $0 }
        }
        for entry in filteredEntries 
        {
            if entry.cftCategory == "Income"
            {
                calculatedTotalAmount += entry.cftAmount
            }
            else
            {
                calculatedTotalAmount -= entry.cftAmount
            }
        }
       
        return calculatedTotalAmount
    }
}
```

The Core data entity is **CFTEntry** and it contains an attribute **cftAccount**. Every time the user displays the SelectAccountView to select an account, the account name is retrieved successfully in the code

```
Text("Account: \(account.cftAccount ?? "")")
```

Within the ContentView, I pass the **entries** variable to **EntryListView**, where it displays a list of CFTEntry records. How can I filter by the *selectedAccount*?

Comment: Pro tip: questions that ask how YOU can solve your own problem tend to do quite well here. Questions that ask how other people can solve your problem, coated with excessive politeness, tend to get downvotes. Readers seem to prefer questions where the author knows they still have to do the work (i.e. there is no "please halp me" at all).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by rearranging the filtering process. No need to *@FetchRequest* in the **ContentView**, because it is more cumbersome to deal with the back-and-forth between **ContentView** and **SelectAccountView**. Since ContentView already captures the *selectedAccount* value, I pass it as argument to the **EntryListView** and carry out the filtering inside.